# Scrollview not scrolling in Android bottomsheet

Tags: android, android-layout, bottom-sheet

I tried the new `BottomSheet` in Android support. Inside the `BottomSheet` I have put a `TextView` and a `ScrollView`. The `BottomSheet`showing just fine, the only problem I found is that the `ScrollView` in the `BottomSheet` is not scrolling. Every time I try to scroll, either the layout in main activity that scroll or the `BottomSheet` changing state from collapse to expand.

This is snippet of my Activity Class code:

```
private BottomSheetBehavior behavior;
View bottomSheet;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    setTextViewOnClickListener(this, findViewById(R.id.parentLayout));

    CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_content);

    // The View with the BottomSheetBehavior
    bottomSheet = coordinatorLayout.findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet);
    behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
    behavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
            // React to state change

        }


        @Override
        public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {
            // React to dragging events
        }
    });

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.tv1:
            setTextViewHeader("Header1");
            setTextViewContent("Long_Text_1");

            break;

        case R.id.tv2:
            setTextViewHeader("Header2");
            setTextViewContent("Long_Text_2");

            break;

        case R.id.tv3:
            setTextViewHeader("Header3");
            setTextViewContent("Long_Text_3");

            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    behavior.setPeekHeight(100);
    behavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
    behavior.setHideable(true);

    bottomSheet.requestLayout();
}
```

This is my Layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.rapidgrowsolutions.android.MainActivity">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv1"
            style="@style/LightRow"
            android:text="some_long_text_here" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv2"
            style="@style/DarkRow"
            android:text="another_long_text_here" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv3"
            style="@style/LightRow"
            android:text="another_long_text_here" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        app:behavior_hideable="true"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">


        <android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FF7733"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvID1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="HEADER"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="9"
                android:background="#ffb773"
                android:fillViewport="true">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvID2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#3377ff"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
            </ScrollView>


        </android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Please post your code for the layout, so that we can check. Also for `ScrollView` to work, it should have only one child under it.

Comment: see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38723483/1718223),that resloved my problem.

Comment: use NestedScrollView instead.

Comment: NestedScrollView without any specific flags, resolves such issues even with BottomSheetDialogFragment.

Answer (score 112):

Hope you figured out this by now, but change `View bottomSheet` to `NestedScrollView bottomSheet`.

Comment: I replaced root <ScrollView ..> to <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView..> and this works, thank you!

Comment: This should be marked as Accepted Answer!

Comment: This is the correct answer! mark it as accepted

Answer (score 5):

Addition to the answer of "jobbert":

If you always return "false" it could happen that the bottomsheet is not working at all. This happend to me, when I also use a viewpager inside the bottom-sheets coordinatorlayout. To actually fix it, one needs to check whether the touch was inside the nestedscrollview or not. This can be calculated easily and leads to the most general solution:

```
 override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(parent: CoordinatorLayout, child: V, event: MotionEvent): Boolean {

    val nested = child.findViewById<NestedScrollView>(R.id.nested) //NestedScrollView
    var x = event.x
    var y = event.y

    val position = IntArray(2)
    nested.getLocationOnScreen(position)

    var nestedX = position[0]
    var nestedY = position[1]


    var boundLeft = nestedX
    var boundRight = nestedX + nested.width
    var boundTop = nestedY
    var boundBottom = nestedY + nested.height


    if ((x > boundLeft && x < boundRight && y > boundTop && y < boundBottom) || event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
        //Touched inside of the scrollview-> pass the touch event to the scrollview
        return false
    }



    //touched outside, use the parents computation to make the bottomsheet work
    return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(parent, child, event)

}
```

Answer (score 4):

I solved the issue by doing below things -

- **First:** don't use ScrollView when you are using CoordinatorLayout instead user NestedScrollView its works much better with CoordinatorLayout.
- **Second:** put a blank view with `android:layout_height` at the bottom, but inside you NestedScrollView
  eg  -

  ```
  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical">

      <ImageView
          android:background="@drawable/username"
          android:id="@+id/userImage_info_search"
          android:layout_gravity="center"
          android:layout_height="100dp"
          android:layout_margin="20dp"
          android:layout_width="100dp" />

      <LinearLayout
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_width="match_parent">

      <View
          android:background="@android:color/black"
          android:layout_height="1dp"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"></View>
  </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:padding="10dp"
      android:weightSum="3">

      <TextView
          style="@style/Bottomsheetstyle"
          android:id="@+id/txtNamelabel_info_search"
          android:layout_gravity="center"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:text="Name" />

      <TextView
          style="@style/Bottomsheetstyle"
          android:id="@+id/txtName_info_search"
          android:layout_gravity="center"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
          android:layout_weight="2"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:text="" />


  </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="match_parent">

      <View
          android:background="@android:color/black"
          android:layout_height="1dp"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"></View>
  </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:padding="10dp"
      android:weightSum="3">

      <TextView
          style="@style/Bottomsheetstyle"
          android:layout_gravity="center"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:text="Number" />

      <LinearLayout
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="2"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:orientation="horizontal">

          <TextView
              style="@style/Bottomsheetstyle"
              android:gravity="center_vertical"
              android:id="@+id/txtNumber_info_search"
              android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
              android:layout_weight="1.4"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:text="+XX (XXX) XXX-XXXX" />

          <ImageView
              android:background="@drawable/call_save"
              android:id="@+id/call_info_search"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_weight="0.3"
              android:layout_width="0dp" />

          <View
              android:layout_gravity="center"
              android:layout_height="5dp"
              android:layout_width="5dp"></View>

          <ImageView
              android:background="@drawable/comment_save"
              android:id="@+id/sms_info_search"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_weight="0.3"
              android:layout_width="0dp" />


      </LinearLayout>


  </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="match_parent">

      <View
          android:background="@android:color/black"
          android:layout_height="1dp"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"></View>
  </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:padding="10dp"
      android:weightSum="3">

      <TextView
          style="@style/Bottomsheetstyle"
          android:layout_gravity="center"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:text="Email" />

      <TextView
          style="@style/Bottomsheetstyle"
          android:id="@+id/txtEmail_info_search"
          android:layout_gravity="center"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
          android:layout_weight="2"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:text="" />


  </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="match_parent">

      <View
          android:background="@android:color/black"
          android:layout_height="1dp"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"></View>
  </LinearLayout>

  <View
      android:background="@android:color/transparent"
      android:layout_height="@dimen/somedp"
      android:layout_width="match_parent" />
  ```

Comment: How does that work? I'm getting a java.lang.IllegalStateException: ScrollView can host only one direct child

Comment: this answer makes no sense at all

Comment: this does not work at all and ends up with exception like ruben said

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me
try using first scrollView and then linear or relative layout
and use also use nested scroll view above it

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    app:behavior_hideable="true"
    app:elevation="4dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"
    android:clipToPadding="true">


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:text="oh hello this is dummy data"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below custom bottom sheet behaviour

```
public class CustomBottomSheetBehaviour<V extends View> extends BottomSheetBehavior {
    public CustomBottomSheetBehaviour() {
        super();
    }

    public CustomBottomSheetBehaviour(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(CoordinatorLayout parent, View child, MotionEvent event) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Aghil C M answer worked, but translated it to Kotlin as auto translate didn't do the trick.

```
class CustomBottomSheetBehaviour<V : View> : BottomSheetBehavior<V> {
    constructor() : super()

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs)

    override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(parent: CoordinatorLayout?, child: V, event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: Must of been a misclick, if you edit I can remove it!

Comment: This will actually lead to new problems. If you always return "false" the bottomsheet won't work when there are multiple children in the coordinatorlayout. See my answer...

Comment: @8KCreativeCommons Not in the time to check it, but seems legit.