# Scrolling issue with BottomSheet - Android

Tags: java, android, bottom-sheet

I need the `BottomSheet` to stop at two positions. I have the following code for `BottomSheet`.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        ....
    </RelativeLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">
           <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:minHeight="1000dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    ....
                </LinearLayout>
          </ScrollView>
     </FrameLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and

```java
View bottomSheet = coordinatorLayout.findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet);
final BottomSheetBehavior behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
behavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
        // React to state change
        Log.e("onStateChanged", "onStateChanged:" + newState);
        if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED) {
            behavior.setPeekHeight(600);
            showAgain.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(false);
        } else if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED) {
            if (behavior.getPeekHeight() == 600) {
                behavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
                behavior.setPeekHeight(80);
                mMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(false);
            } else if (behavior.getPeekHeight() == 80) {
                showAgain.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(true);
            }
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {
        // React to dragging events
        Log.e("onSlide", "onSlide " + slideOffset);
    }
});
    
behavior.setPeekHeight(600);
```

This code works fine except one thing. The very first time I have to scroll up the `BottomSheet` and then I can down scroll it. I cannot directly down scroll the sheet.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 32):

I don't know if this will be a solution to your problem, but I fixed quite a bit of scroll issues in a `BottomSheet` by replacing the `ScrollView` in the `BottomSheet` with a `NestedScrollView`.

Comment: Absolutely right! `NestedScrollView` without any specific flags, resolves such issues even with `BottomSheetDialogFragment`. I experienced the same!

Answer (score 7):

Hope here you will find a solution

https://www.androidhive.info/2017/12/android-working-with-bottom-sheet/

and change `ScrollView` with `NestedScrollView`

p.s. Actually there's too mush code there

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me,

- Set a Nested Scrollview as the parent
- Make recycler view height wrap_content