# BottomSheetDialog alignment of views when using the same layout to show full view and half view

Tags: android, android-layout, bottom-sheet, android-bottomsheetdialog, bottomsheetdialogfragment

I have a layout (named mirroring.xml) and I need to use it in two different activities. First activity, needs the content to be displayed based on the full length and width of the android mobile. The second activity uses layout to show only half the screen. And to achieve this, I am using a bottomSheetDialog and BottomSheetFragment. But since I use same layout for both the full and half view, the full screen view works fine, but the half screen view, cut's off some of the views, and the alignment of the views are not proper. Do I need to use a separate layout in this case for the half screen view using the bottomSheetDialog ?

Comment: In both case  display content is same or diffrenet ?

Comment: @Arbaz.in : In both the cast the display content is the same.

Comment: Did you try with NestedScrollView ? if not then try this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41680628/5995648)